# Saving and loading objects with arraylist properties of other custom objects (Android)

Tags: android

I am a total beginner in android and learning how to use JSon/Gson to save and load data. I was working on an app of my own and couldn't find a way to go about saving and loading my "students" arraylist that I created in my MainActivity that has two arraylist properties of custom objects. (I'm not sure if this is good design. It just felt right. I would appreciate any commentary about this as I'm learning on my own and would love the feedback) Thanks so much in advance!

```
public class Student {
private String name;
private String number;
ArrayList<Homework> homework;
ArrayList<Exam> exam;
}


public class Exam {
private String name;
private String grade;
}



public class Homework {
private int status;
private String date;
}





public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.student_list);



    }
}
```

Comment: so, how you store your array list?

Comment: Yeah, storing the data in my arraylist to the disk on closing the app and loading the stored data when the app is opened.

Comment: if you want get data on apps open use SharedPreference to achieve that, read here `https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html`

Answer (score 0):

To save data to arraylist you can do this ,
`homework.add(status,date);`